# Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

Просто установил Android Studio, попробовал запустить шаблонный проект, процессор intel поддерживает виртуализацию и она включена, проект собирается, но не запускается на эмуляторе с вот такой вот ошибкой. Ранее (пару лет назад) я уже ставил студию на этот же ноут и тоже с windows 10, тогда эмулятор работал нормально. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: у вас включен Hyper-V в системе?

Comment: Хмм попробуйте в AndroidStudio на вкладке Help (верхнее меню) нажать Find Action,там ввести registry, кликнуть на выделенный элемент. Найдите "debugger.attach.to.process.action" (введите attach). Отключите этот пункт. Есть шанс, что поможет.

Comment: @Andrew, спасибо, я включил, но ошибка не исчезла

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, спасибо, попробовал, ошибка сохранилась

Comment: А другие проекты запускаются на эмуляторе? Можно ли запустить эмулятор не через запуск проекта а напрямую?